# Change Validations in beforeInsert and beforeUpdate

Tags: grails, groovy

I have one Domain class

```
class Store{
    String name
    Store hierarchy
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    static hasMany=[storeRestrictions:StoreRestrictions]
    boolean isBillable
    boolean isConsignment
    boolean isMassUploadPossible

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable:false,blank:false,maxSize:50,unique:true)
        hierarchy(nullable:true,blank:true)
        dateCreated()
        lastUpdated()
        isBillable()
        isMassUploadPossible()
        storeRestrictions(nullable:false)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to change the validations in `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate`, for example, so that if `isConsignment` is true then `storeRestrictions` can become `nullable:true`?

Comment: No - you should be able to use custom validator inconstraints though

Answer (score 0):

I think [custom validators](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) are the right thing for your requisites. You can replace the nullable:true constrain on storeRestrictions with a custom validator that check the isConsignment value

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
static constraints = {
    ...
    storeRestrictions(validator: {field, inst -> 
                                    if( false == isConsignment) 
                                        return null != inst.storeRestrictions
                     )
}
```

Read more at [Grails Validator](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html)